# Azure Storage Table query by DateTime not returning any results

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to display entries in an Azure Storage Table based on their "Time" fields which is a `DateTime` object. However, I'm not having any luck when I'm trying to query based on the `DateTime`.

I tried different conditions like:

1. time = g.Time
2. time.Equals(g.Time)
3. time.Ticks == g.Time.Ticks
4. time.ToString() == g.Time.ToString()
5. time.ToString().Equals(g.Time.ToString())

   ```
       DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(timePoint);
       TableServiceContext tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
       var query = from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntry>(tableName)
                      where time.Ticks == g.Time.Ticks
                   select g;
   ```

I have displayed entries based on a different `string` field successfully, but now that I want to use a `DateTime`, it's not working properly.

Do you have to handle `DateTime` objects differently? Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I verified that time is equal to at least one entry when I create the entries to put in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by making the time my partition key with the following condition:

```
where g.PartitionKey.Equals(time.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"))
```

However, I'm still not clear on why this works while the other methods of searching don't work.

Comment: I think rowkey and partition key are simple string value, and only string comparison may work. Other comparison just use the ToString() to compare.